Unable to share Sharepoint folder to external users through graph API
I'm trying to programmatically share a SharePoint folder with a bunch of external users. I have two external users, call them UserManual and UserProgram. UserManual was created when I shared an old version of the SharePoint folder with him manually from inside the SharePoint application.  That folder no longer exists, but the users is still listed in EntraID.  UserProgram was created using the graph API:
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations"
    body = {
        "invitedUserEmailAddress": email,
        "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite",
        "sendInvitationMessage": True,
        "invitedUserDisplayName": email.split('@')[0]
    }
    response = requests.post(url, headers=get_headers(access_token), json=body)

I get a successful response to the request and the user shows up in EntraID. Looking at the two users in Entra or by doing a GET on their user object, I don't see any difference between them besides name/email.
Next, I share a link to the new folder with each of them:
    url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/{folder_id}/createLink"
    body = {
      "type": "view",
      "scope": "users",
      "recipients": [
        {
          "email": user_email,
        }
      ]
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=get_headers(access_token), json=body)

I get a successful response to this request for each user, and a subsequent request to the permissions endpoint returns a permissions object granting both users "view" on the same link. Again, the only difference between the two users is their name/email. The problem is that UserManual can access the link, but UserProgram gets access denied. Since I shared the link the same way for both users, I don't think it has anything to do with the createLink. There must be a difference between the users themselves. I've retrieved their user definition (/users/{principal_name}), their memberships (/users/{principal_name}/memberOf), appRoleAssignments, and a bunch of other stuff that I thought might show a difference. I can't find anything different between them. What extra magic is SharePoint applying to the user when I share a folder manually that I am forgetting to do programmatically?
I've tried using different methods for sharing the folder (invite vs link), and I've tried different options on the user invitation (sending a message, not sending a message). I've waited for the user invitation link to come to an email inbox and accepted that invitation before attempting to share the folder. I've waited 24 hours after creating the invite before sharing the folder. I've signed out of all sessions, closed browser windows, restarted my computer, and begged Copilot for any suggestions. I'm out of ideas.
